# Spherical Coordinates Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the notation of wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

, is it true that we can switch the boundaries of $\varphi$ and $\theta$ ? 
i.e :
$\varphi \in [0,\pi] $  and $\theta \in [0,2\pi ] $?

I think the answer is "no" , but want to verify my answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not?${}{}{}$

Comment: Answer is yes..